# Pollers and Memory Leaks

Tags: spring-integration

I came across the following in the spring integration reference doc

> The receiveTimeout property specifies the amount of time the poller should wait if no messages are available when it invokes the receive operation. For example, consider two options that seem similar on the surface but are actually quite different: the first has an interval trigger of 5 seconds and a receive timeout of 50 milliseconds while the second has an interval trigger of 50 milliseconds and a receive timeout of 5 seconds. The first one may receive a message up to 4950 milliseconds later than it arrived on the channel (if that message arrived immediately after one of its poll calls returned). On the other hand, the second configuration will never miss a message by more than 50 milliseconds. The difference is that the second option requires a thread to wait, but as a result it is able to respond much more quickly to arriving messages. This technique, known as long polling, can be used to emulate event-driven behavior on a polled source.

Based on my experience, the second option can cause a problem because an interval of 50 milliseconds will make the poller run every 50 millies, but if there's no messages to pick up each threads created will wait for 5 seconds for a message to appear. In that 5 seconds the poller will get executed another 100 times, potentially creating another 100 threads, etc.

This quickly runs away.

My question is did I misunderstand the way this all works? Because if I'm correct I think the reference documentation should be changed, or at least a warning added.

```
e<bean id="store" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="channelServerDataSource"/>
    <property name="channelMessageStoreQueryProvider" ref="queryProvider"/>
    <property name="region" value="${user.name}_${channel.queue.region:default}"/>
    <property name="usingIdCache" value="false"/>
</bean> 

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
    <int:after-commit expression="@store.removeFromIdCache(headers.id.toString())" />
    <int:after-rollback expression="@store.removeFromIdCache(headers.id.toString())"/> 
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<int:channel id="transacitonAsyncServiceQueue">
    <int:queue message-store="store"/> 
    <!--  <int:queue/>  --> 
</int:channel>

<bean id="rxPollingTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger">
    <constructor-arg value="500"/>
    <constructor-arg value="MILLISECONDS"/>
    <property name = "initialDelay" value = "30000"/> 
    <!-- initialDelay important to ensure channel doesnt start processing before the datasources have been initialised becuase we
         now persist transactions in the queue, at startup (restart) there maybe some ready to go which get processed before the
         connection pools have been created which happens when the servlet is first hit -->
</bean> 

<int:service-activator ref="asyncChannelReceiver" method="processMessage" input-channel="transacitonAsyncServiceQueue">
    <int:poller trigger="rxPollingTrigger" max-messages-per-poll="20"  task-executor="taskExecutor" receive-timeout="400">
        <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManagerAsyncChannel" /> 
    </int:poller>
    <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <ref bean="databaseSessionContext" />
    </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int:service-activator>

<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="100-200" queue-capacity="200" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is did I misunderstand the way this all works?

Yes, you misunderstand.

The trigger (in this case a `PeriodicTrigger` with an interval of 50ms) is only consulted to calculate the next poll time when the current poll exits.

There is only one poller thread running concurrently. If there is no message, the poll thread is suspended for 5 seconds; the trigger is then consulted (`t.nextExecutionTime()`) and the next poll is scheduled for `+50ms`; so, with no data a single thread will run every 5.05 seconds.

When messages are present, and you wish to have a concurrency greater than one, you would use a task executor to allow the poller thread to hand off to another thread so that the trigger is immediately consulted for the next poll time.

> Based on my experience

Please clarify "your experience" and show configuration, evidence etc.

If you have a suspected thread leak, the first step, generally, is to take a thread dump to figure out what they are all doing.

**EDIT**: (in response to your comments below).

There's not really a downside of CALLER_RUNS in this scenario because, although the current thread "jumps ahead" of the queued tasks, it's not like this poll has newer data than the queued tasks, it's just a poll after all. However, poller threads are a limited resource (although the limit can be changed) so long-running tasks on a poller thread are generally discouraged.

ABORT could cause some noise in the logs; an alternative is to configure a [PollSkipAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/whats-new.html#4.1-PollSkipAdvice) where the advice can look at the task queue and silently ignore the current poll. In 4.2, we've [added even more flexibility to the poller](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#__smart_polling).

You will find many articles on the internet that say that using RDBMS as a queue is not the greatest idea; you might want to consider a JMS or rabbitmq-backed channel instead. If you are tied to JDBC, you should be sure to use the `JdbcChannelMessageStore` and not the `JdbcMessageStore`. The former is preferred for backing channels since it only uses 1 table; the latter has some performance issues when used to back a channel, because of contention on the message group table. See [Backing Message Channels in the JDBC Support chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-message-store-channels) for more information.

Comment: Hi, "Based On My Experience" was to do with a previous question I had posted on the old Spring forum, which I now cannot find (username I think is Tim.Taylor you did answer another poster recently on Stackoverflow with a reference to one of my posts that you answered on the Spring Forum concerning max-mesaages-per-poll)

Comment: My old question which I can no longer find on either site was about a memory leak I had that I'm sure was because I had set up the interval trigger to be shorter than the receive timeout while using a task:executor for concurrency,  Maybe I missunderstood that answer as well - or I'm remembering it incorrectly, either is poss

Comment: If you use a task executor with a poller you need to constrain the concurrency with a bounded task executor, for example, use a thread pool with a bounded queue. When no threads are available and the queue is full, the executor can be configured to abort the poll, or simply run this poll on the poller thread (CALLER_RUNS policy), thus suspending the polling until the current poll completes. If you use an unbounded task executor then, yes, you could run out of memory quite quickly.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I'm using a bounded executor:  _<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="100-200" queue-capacity="200" keep-alive="1" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />_

Comment: So, moving on, if we had an interval trigger of 50ms and a timeout of 5 seconds plus a thread pool, all the threads in the pool would be used waiting for a message to arrive on the channel correct?  May be that's what I was what my previous post was relating to.

Comment: Yes, it's generally better to keep the receive timeout close to the poll rate when using a task executor. Another technique that might be suitable would be to use a single threaded poller and have it hand off after a successful poll (e.g. using an `ExecutorChannel` downstream).

Comment: This would be a problem for transactions though (using an Executor Channel)? I'm trying to make the channel transactional, so if the thread doing the work on the database rolls back, which can happen if the connection to the database fails, the message rolls back and ends up back in the channels queue, which is persisted to a store (database). I cannot afford to lose any messages.

Comment: That is correct. You need to tweak the timeout and polling interval to avoid having lots of threads sitting waiting.

Comment: One last thing on this. (thanks for your help by the way), I noticed I have set my task-executor rejection-policy to CALLER_RUNS. If it gets to that point that I have no more threads (I also have a queue-capacity set), does that mean it will run the poller thread, is this a good idea?  I'm thinking of changing it to ABORT. The reason I'm asking all this is I'm having some issues when the database slows down at certain times due to running jobs. My channel queue message-store backs up as expected, and all the threads in the task executor get used up.

Comment: cont/. The issue I have is when the database resolves its issues and my transactions stop timing out, sometimes if the queue is over about 3000 messages it struggles to recover for some reason and Im trying to figure out why. I suspect its not Spring integration but the connection pool is maxed out with connections that have been closed (timed out), but Im just analysing the channel and pollers to see if perhaps I've created too much capacity and trying to process too many backed up messages at once and the whole thing grinds down.

Comment: ok, I've been thinking about my issue a bit more and am wondering if the CALLER_RUNS is actually the reason why my recovery takes so long. My task-executor has a queue-capacity = 200 which means if the database is having performance issues, it will get used up pretty quickly at which point the poller thread will be used. Currently when things go bad connections are rolled back (implicitly) at transaction boundaries because the "connection is already closed" - I think closed/timed out by the database after 3 minutes or so.

Comment: That means potentially the poller thread could get stuck for 3 minutes as it takes a message from the task-executor queue and tries to processes it, probably gets held up waiting for a connection from the connection pool. Under normal conditions the task executor has max 10 active threads. I'm thinking because the issue isn't abnormal load but an abnormally slow database (the reason for that is still unclear, but I'm pretty sure its due to customer running jobs or some networking issue) last thing I need is to hit it with too many threads.

Comment: I think I may try reducing the number of threads in the task executor pool and possibly reduce dramatically the queue-capacity. AS long as there is enough for normal to high load when the database is good Ill be ok. Then also change the rejection policy to abort (log noise is ok). I'm on spring integration 2.2.4. I could add an advice to the int:service-activator I guess to maybe check the store queue size?)

Comment: why not making receiveTmeout = 0 (default value is 1 sec)? then poller will run as planned for fixedDelay mode. very strange approach by default.